# Why are multidimensional models not supported in Azure Analysis Services?

Tags: azure, ssas, olap, ssas-tabular, olap-cube

I am trying to migrate a multidimensional database (OLAP data cube) from SQL Server Analysis Services to Azure Analysis Services. To my surprise, I found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-overview that "Multidimensional models and PowerPivot for SharePoint are not supported in Azure Analysis Services." Why is it that Microsoft is not supporting multidimensional models in Azure Analysis Services? I have never used tabular models but I imagine my option would be to make a conversion of my OLAP data cube, into an equivalent tabular model. Is there any other alternative to deploy OLAP data cubes in the cloud on Azure technologies?

Comment: While Microsoft initially supported both multidimensional and tabular models in Analysis Services, they decided to focus on tabular models in the cloud with Azure Analysis Services. While the transition from a multidimensional model to a tabular model might seem challenging, it can provide benefits in terms of performance, scalability, and future-proofing your analytics solutions. Converting your OLAP data cube into an equivalent tabular model is viable option and Microsoft provides tools and documentation to help with this migration process. In short, The only way is to convert to tabular.

Comment: Regarding the reasons why, we can only guess, but I think it has something to do with the fact that tabular models are designed to leverage in-memory columnar storage, which aligns well with modern data processing (Since cloud focuses on modern not legacy, but also ability to scale to big data). This design allows for faster query performance and easier integration with other Azure services. OLAP datacube is not cloud native.

Comment: applications like SSIS, SSAS are legacy applications whether customers like it or not. They should only be used when the other options are strictly not possible to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my comments, I Wanted to leave here the documentation that explicity states

"Multidimensional mode is only available with SQL Server Analysis Services. If you want your models deployed to Azure Analysis Services or Power BI, you can stop reading now. Multidimensional models will not be supported in Azure Analysis Services or Power BI Premium datasets. If you want multidimensional models in the cloud, the only way is to deploy SQL Server Analysis Services in Multidimensional mode to an Azure VM."

("the only way" is rather inconvenient, and adds a complexity layer so I didnt consider it in my comments")

and also:

"SQL Server Analysis Services also includes Power Pivot for SharePoint mode, which remains supported for SharePoint 2016 and SharePoint 2013, however, Microsoft's BI strategy has shifted away from Power Pivot in Excel integration with SharePoint. Power BI and Power BI Report Server are now the recommended platforms to host Excel workbooks with Power Pivot models. As such, this article now excludes a Power Pivot for SharePoint comparison."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/comparing-tabular-and-multidimensional-solutions-ssas?view=asallproducts-allversions

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other alternative to deploy OLAP data cubes in the cloud on Azure technologies?

You can always run SSAS on Azure VMs.  There's a Marketplace image for it here:

[Azure Marketplace - SQL Server 2022 Analysis Services](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/microsoftpowerbi.ssas-2022-gen2?tab=Overview)

With this solution you can choose your own storage configuration, which is more important in Multdimensional than it is in Tabular.

Comment: Are multidimensional databases a legacy technology that will soon be discontinued and unsupported? I know it is possible to run SSAS on Azure VMs, as I could run it by installing SQL Server on my local computer. But I am wondering if the purpose of Microsoft with still allowing multidimensional databases to run on SQL Server is not to be too drastic, and giving developers sufficient time for the learning curve, and to migrate their systems to the tabular model.

Comment: Multi-dimensional models are still part of the 2022 release, which means they will continue to be supported for the normal 5+5 support lifecycle.  And there are no plans to discontinue the feature.  However more customers are using Tabular for new work than Mult-Dimensional, and the engineering focus of the development team is focused more on Tabular.

Comment: @JaimeMontoya, I think I confused everyone here by saying legacy, but the meaning of the word means different things to different people. By legacy I meant more like old tech that is still in use, but newer alternatives are available, not to imply that its going to be discontinued (I honestly do not know). The problem I think with hosting it in the VM is that what if the vm fails ?